# Fork not showing child pid on mother

Tags: c, unix, fork

I just started working with Fork and made this to understand how it really works, normally on the mother side, when i print the variable `a` i should get the child process ID but its giving me zero

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void main(){

    int a;
    a=fork();
    if(a==0){
        printf("Child Process, pid= %d, mother id: %d", getpid(), getppid());
        exit(0);
    }else{
        wait(&a);
        printf("Mother Process, Child pid= %d, mother's pid= %d ", a, getpid());    

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: what is `a` _before_ the call to `wait`?

Answer (score 7):

You're using `wait` incorrectly. It's defined as follows:

```
pid_t wait(int *stat_loc)
```

so when you're calling it like

```
wait(&a);
```

you're ignoring the return value, which would be the child's PID and replacing what was the child PID that `fork` returned with the exit status returned by the child.

If you put the `printf` statement before the wait, you'll see that `a` already had the child's PID in it. And calling `wait` correctly and then repeating the output should give the same results...although in the example below I've also included the status result too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void main(){

    int a;
    a=fork();
    if(a==0){
        printf("Child Process, pid= %d, mother id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        exit(0);
    }else{
        int status;
        printf("Mother Process, Child pid= %d, mother's pid= %d\n", a, getpid());    
        a=wait(&status);
        printf("Mother Process, Child pid= %d, mother's pid= %d, status = %d\n", a, getpid(), status);    

    }

}
```